# Wordpress Multisite - Get plugin to pull info from a single install on mainsite

Tags: wordpress, api, multisite

I am using a plugin that needs to be setup on each individual sub site so that an api key can be activated.

Is there a way to change wp-config or the plugin data so that the subsites pull their plugin information from the network install page vs the individual plugin activation in order to avoid having to install and activate on each subsite?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the plugin is not made for multisite. You cannot simply change that. Either the plugin source code has to be modified or you can make a new plugin that tries to modify how the plugin works.

The second option is recommended and I imagine it should hide the settings page on each individual site and also filter the option where the API data is saved. In any case, it is a job for a programmer who can make WordPress plugins.